# Android SSL Client authentication error using PKI applet client certificate and private key

Tags: android, ssl, smartcard, pki, ssl-client-authentication

I'm trying to send a HTTPS request to Tax Core API. It worked fine until Android 10, but ever since it came out I'm having trouble sending HTTPS requests, because client authentication is unsuccessful.

Before I was just getting client certificate from the PKI applet (installed on smart card I was provided by TaxCore) and made a custom RSA private key that actually had only modulus from public key I got from client certificate. This was the only way to authenticate and it worked. Now I'm getting error with RSA_signing and encryption.

Just to add, signing process is executed on the smart card via custom Provider for signing, since I can't read secret element .

I tried setting other Providers like BouncyCastle, but nothing changed. I tried other Keystores besides PCS12 I'm currently using, but I couldn't get them to work.